# Info on Mangaka Strike/Ball Tanaka?

Tags: mangaka

My school has a Manga Club and we are trying to find more information on the creator of Servamp. Anyone know where we can find some more details about her life and maybe a picture of what she looks like?

We'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I tried using all my google skills, but I have only found [this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/showbizsuperstar/3181790216), which may or may not be her...

Comment: Wow! How did you even find that? I'll keep looking into it but this is more than what we could turn up. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well, I used Google Images with the term "Tanaka Strike", and the image was in the third row. :D